# Zap Jenkins plugin Ubuntu configuration

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-14.04, jenkins-plugins, zap

I am integrating Zap as a part of CI build in Jenkins with Zap jenkins plugin. How to set ZAPROXY_HOME IN UBUNTU to execute Zap and my Jenkins is installed in ubuntu server

Comment: Have you tried asking this on the ZAP Jenkins Plugin group? https://groups.google.com/forum/#%21forum/zaproxy-jenkins